# Must i use a polymorphic setup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a app setup question: (for a travel site)

My models are

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end
class House < ActiveRecord::Base
end
class Apartment < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Boutique < ActiveRecord::Base
end
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
end
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I want to add a "i've been there", "i've done that", "i want to go there" ect to the user model. So when a user/visitor is by example on the activity show page there is a function where they can add the status describe above.

Where do i start in relation with my db setup...must i use the polymorphic setup?

Thanks..remco

Answer (score 0):

I believe we need more information as to how the models relate to each other rather than just saying "I want to add `I've been there`, `I've done that`". We need relevant information i.e. A user `has_many ????` A house `belongs_to ???`. Please see [ActiveRecord Association basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). This will help gain some more clarity on what you are trying to do.